# How do I find the language declaration for this Chinese website?

Tags: html

I need to record some detailed info for a number of web pages.  Most of this info I've been finding by inspecting each page's HTML code.

For the language attribute, I've been searching 'lang', 'language', and 'content-language' if the info isn't readily available in the metadata or header.  Which until now has been working.

I'm stumped on a Chinese site.  I've scrolled though a lot of the site's code, but I'm not familiar with HTML or XML or website programming in general, so I don't know whether I'm looking in the wrong spot or if I should be looking for something else entirely.

This is the individual [product page](http://zhushou.360.cn/detail/index/soft_id/2844111?recrefer=SE_D_%E5%A5%A5%E6%96%AF%E5%8D%A1) I started at.  I've looked at the code for the [main site](http://zhushou.360.cn/) too with no luck.

Comment: I'm very puzzled by the choice of "unclear what you're asking" for the close votes. I thought that the question was fairly self-explanatory. The only issue I can see is that there are links to an external site whose markup cannot be reasonably reproduced as code within the question. Even so, surely the general problem of determining the language of a site based on information it declares to the user agent isn't *that* broad.

Comment: Appreciate the answer and the defense. I know the language is pretty obviously Chinese, but this was the first site I came across where it wasn't declared. And I'm including the code as part of the record, so wanted to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all websites declare their content language explicitly. If you cannot find any `lang` HTML attributes, and the site doesn't send a Content-Language header, you'll just have to guess the language by analyzing the contents of the page.